# CSS dynamic position of tooltip on hover with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

I'm writing a simple tooltip that can hold HTML tags. Please check http://jsfiddle.net/Qkwm8/ for the demo.

I want the tooltip box to show properly regardless of the position of element, in this case `<a>`, that shows tooltips on mouseover event.

The tooltips are shown fine except when `<a>` floats right (or is at the end of the line) or at the bottom of the screen where it doesn't show properly, it appears off the screen

If the `<a>` floats right, or at the end of the line, or is at the bottom of the screen,  I want the tooltip to change position so it remains visible

Thank you.

> Update demo link

here's the complete result: http://jsfiddle.net/Qkwm8/3/

Comment: do you want to flip the tooltip to the left if there no window space on right hand side,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the document width to check how wide the html document is and adjust the left position accordingly. Say:

```
    //set  the left position
    var left = $(this).offset().left + 10;
    if(left + 200 > $(document).width()){
        left = $(document).width() - 200;   
    }
```

I used 200 here because you are setting your tooltip to 200px wide. Something similar can be done with height.

There is also a window width but I always get confused about the difference so you should check which one gives you better results.

An example of the bottom of the page is:

```
   //set the height, top position
    var height = $(this).height();
    var top = $(this).offset().top;
    if(top + 200 > $(window).height()){
        top = $(window).height() - 200 - height;
    }
```

Again, using 200 since you are setting your tooltip to 200px height.

Comment: @Narazana You can do it in a similar manner to the way the left worked. Instead use the height() function. I'll edit the answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks, Vicent. I finally did it. I just updated the question to include the latest update demo at http://jsfiddle.net/Qkwm8/3/

Comment: @VincentRamdhanie Dear Vincent Ramdhanie can you check my question. [STACKOVERFLOW](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822445/css-hover-card-positioning)

Answer (score 0):

$('a.show-tooltips').mouseover(function() {

if(($(this).parent()).css('float')) =="right") add the proper class to left

else -> the proper class the right
....
}