# CSS hover card positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a hover card with `css`. I have one question about position of the page down.

I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/mCIkt)** page from codepen.io . So if you are in bottom of the demo page then you see bubble `div` shows up.

What should I do to show the `.bubble` at the bottom of the triangle down the page?
[image]

```
.container{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  margin:0px auto;
  margin-top:50px;
}
.bubble 
{
position: absolute;
width: 250px;
height: 120px;
padding: 0px;
background: #000;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
  display:none;
}

.bubble:after 
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 15px 15px;
border-color: #000 transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
top: -15px;
left: 194px;
}
.hub:hover .bubble{
  display:block;
}
.wrp{
  width:300px;
  height:68px;
}
```

Comment: I could be wrong but I think you are going to need javascript to check the bounds

Comment: @Timmerz you are right about this. But I could not find a sample application.

Comment: What browser are you using? Because in FF latest version IT works good. tried your DEMO in full page here: http://codepen.io/shadowman86/full/mCIkt

Comment: @innovation, keep in mind that if you do not award the bounty, half will be given to the highest-voted answer.  You will not be returned any bounty.

Comment: @CliffBurton I just need help from that question. But i don't understand why someone gives me downvote. I undelete my question again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## EDIT

> **I have made a jQuery plugin that addresses this issues, repositions the tooltip to stay inside window, simple & responsive. You can see it in action here [tipso](http://tipso.object505.com)**

I forked your codepen and reworked it [on codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEWvvx)

I guess this is what you are looking for :)

```
$('.hub').on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $(this).addClass('zIndex');

    var top, left,
      toolTipWidth = 250,
      toolTipHeight = 120,
      arrowHeight = 15,
      elementHeight = $(this).height(),
      elementWidth = $(this).width(),
      documentHeight = $(window).height(),
      bounding = $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect(),
      topHub = bounding.top;


    if (topHub < topHub + toolTipHeight && topHub + toolTipHeight + arrowHeight + elementHeight <= documentHeight) {

      $('.bubble').addClass('top');
      top = elementHeight + arrowHeight;
      left = -(elementWidth / 2);

    }

    if (topHub + toolTipHeight + arrowHeight + elementHeight >= documentHeight) {
      $('.bubble').addClass('bottom');
      top = -toolTipHeight - arrowHeight;
      left = -(elementWidth / 2);
    }


    $('.bubble').css({
      'top': top,
      'left': left
    });
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $('.bubble').removeClass('top bottom');
    $(this).removeClass('zIndex');
  }
});
```

Comment: is it possible to add `time` for hover. Like when you hover on a div  then `.bubble` open after a few second ?